# get all values by a specific key in a deep nested dict using python

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test",
    "fils": [
        {"id": 2, "name": "Test", "fils": []},
        {"id": 4, "name": "Test", "fils": []},
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Test",
            "fils": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "Test",
                    "fils": [{"id": 14, "name": "test", "fils": []}],
                }
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```

so my goal is to get all the id's which are [1,2,4,5,12,14].
is there any way to get that using a recursive function or in an another way?

Comment: "Is there a way?" Yes.

Comment: I suggest you break this into smaller pieces. In fact, that is a fundamental concept of recursion. Solve the problem with the simplest example then build up from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion. If `dct` is your dictionary from the question, then:

```py
def get_ids(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k == "id":
                yield v
            else:
                yield from get_ids(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from get_ids(v)


ids = list(get_ids(dct))
print(ids)
```

Prints:

```py
[1, 2, 4, 5, 12, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use an iterative approach:

```
def get_ids(adict, key):
    stack = [adict]
    result = []

    while stack:
        elem = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(elem, dict):
            for k, v in elem.items():
                if k == key:
                    result.append(v)
                stack.append(v)
        elif isinstance(elem, list):
            stack.extend(elem)
    return result
```